# What is the mathematical explanation of adding 2d Array and 1d Array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, julia, linear-algebra

I can't seem to replicate this numpy arithmetic. I'm using Julia, but want to know the mathematical explanation for this code. It seems to break what I know about Linear Algebra.

```py
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.2).reshape(-1, 1)

X.shape  ## (50, 1)

test = np.sum(X**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(X**2, 1)

test.shape  ## (50, 50)
```

In Julia, I would write

```
X = reshape(collect(range(-5, stop=5, length=N)), :, 1);

size(X)  ## (50, 1)

test = sum(X.^2, dims=2) + vec(sum(X.^2, dims=2));

size(test) ## (50, 1)
```

I'm trying to think how a 50x50 matrix would be the result of adding two vectors? I know numpy uses a lot of broadcasting under the hood, but it doesn't seem clear to me what this is doing.

What is the mathematical notation or Julia equivalent for what numpy is doing here?

Comment: numpy [broadcasts](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  If you don't want that to happen, don't add the dangling dimension of size `1`

Comment: Also, the summation and then reshaping doesn't change the data at all, so it's confusing why you are doing it.

Comment: I find it confusing too. I'm following a GP tutorial found here: https://katbailey.github.io/post/gaussian-processes-for-dummies/ I want to recreate this in Julia, but also trying to understand the math at the same time.

Comment: The constructions are needlessly complicated. Just write `X = range(-5, 5, length=N)`. No need for `collect` and `reshape`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your are doing a lot of stuff that really obscures your point, which, I believe, concerns how to add arrays of different shapes.

Python:

```
In [21]: x = np.random.rand(5, 1)                                               

In [22]: x.shape                                                                
Out[22]: (5, 1)

In [23]: y = np.random.rand(1, 4)                                               

In [24]: y.shape                                                                
Out[24]: (1, 4)

In [25]: (x + y).shape                                                          
Out[25]: (5, 4)
```

Julia:

```
julia> x = rand(5);

julia> y = rand(1, 4);

julia> x + y
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("dimensions must match")

julia> x .+ y
5×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.95779  1.31897   1.23345   1.32423 
 1.78126  1.14244   1.05692   1.14771 
 1.08306  0.444243  0.35872   0.449509
 1.69756  1.05874   0.97322   1.06401 
 1.18661  0.547789  0.462265  0.553054

julia> size(x .+ y)
(5, 4)
```

As you can tell, Python broadcasts arrays by default, while Julia requires that you specifically ask for it, by using the dot operator, `.`.

It is exactly because it does not make sense to add two arrays of different shapes, that Julia does not broadcast by default. Similarly, with multiplication, `*` and `.*` differ:

```
julia> A = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> B = [4 5; 6 7]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5
 6  7

julia> A * B
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 16  19
 36  43

julia> A .* B
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
  4  10
 18  28
```

The ordinary `*` is matrix multiplication, while the latter is elementwise array multiplication.

Another example:

```
julia> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6

julia> b = [7, 8]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 7
 8

julia> A * b
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (2,3), vector B has length 2")

julia> A .* b
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
  7  14  21
 32  40  48
```

Comment: I prefer Julia's syntax much better. I suppose the only way to tell what happening in numpy is to know the shape of arrays before hand. I like that Julia requires us to be specific, so it's obvious when we are "breaking" rules.